# How to navigate in cmakelists.txt?

Tags: cmake, build, directory

I have project dependency packages in the directory

C:/Users/king/my/mytest/dds

mytest contains folders dds, Source, testapp

I use the following in my cmakelists.txt

```
find_package(Idlpp-cxx REQUIRED PATHS C:/Users/king/my/mytest/dds/Idlpp-cxx)

find_package(CycloneDDS REQUIRED PATHS C:/Users/king/my/mytest/dds/CycloneDDS)

find_package(CycloneDDS-CXX REQUIRED PATHS C:/Users/king/my/mytest/dds/CycloneDDS-CXX)
```

how can I set them to pick up automatically without hardcoding **C:/Users/king/my/mytest/**? which will differ from pc to pc....

I do cmake build in this folder

C:/Users/king/my/mytest/testapp

cmaklists.txt file is in

C:/Users/king/my/mytest/Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR can be used to pick any forward directory from the current directory

```
 Idlpp-cxx PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my/mytest/dds/idlpp-cxx)
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

> New in version 3.12: Search paths specified in the `<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake variable and the `<PackageName>_ROOT` environment variable, where `<PackageName>` is the package to be found.

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure